# Why position: sticky doesn't work when ancestor is overflow: scroll?

Tags: html, css, css-position, sticky

When using `position: sticky` on an element, the element sticks at the position I want in the window.

But when an ancestor has any `overflow` value set (`scroll`, `hidden`, or `auto`) other than `visible`, the element suddenly doesn't stick anymore.

[Here's a CodePen with an example. Try to remove and add `overflow: scroll` on `main` in CSS.](https://codepen.io/ghivert/pen/GRgbdGa)

```css
main {
  overflow: scroll;
  background: #eee;
  min-height: 200vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  background: lightblue;
  flex: 2;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: pink;
  flex: 1;
}

footer {
  background: lightyellow;
  flex: 2;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Sticky</title>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <header>Hello</header>
    <div class="sticky">I'm sticky</div>
    <footer>I'm the footer</footer>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to understand why it behaves like this. I know the result, but I don't understand why. I tried to read the MDN documentation which talks about scrolling context, but I didn't get it.
Do someone can explain it easily according to the CSS spec?

Comment: https://codepen.io/dannievinther/pen/exvOda Maybe this can help you

Comment: @CarlosDelCuraPascual Keep in mind the `overscroll` spec is a draft spec and shouldn't yet be used in production environments.

Comment: @TylerH I know... [Can I Use ... ](https://caniuse.com/#search=overscroll)